# Signals not working anymore after QObjects being moved into QThreads

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

Basically, the title... if there is no QThread (or it is just commented) I get the following result:

```
LOG> Log working!
LOG> PRODUCER: sent resource address: 29980624
PRODUCER: sent resource address: 29980624
CONSUMER: received resource address: 29980624
```

29980624, or any relevant memory position.

But, when un-commented just

```
LOG> Log working!
```

mainwindow.h

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void slot_log(QString str);

signals:
    void signal_log(QString str);

private:
    void createConsumer( void );
    void deleteConsumer( void );
    void createProducer( void );
    void deleteProducer( void );
    void createConnections( void );
    SingleConsumer *consumer;
    QThread *thread_consumer;
    SingleProducer *producer;
    QThread *thread_producer;
};
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    createConsumer();
    createProducer();
    createConnections();
    QTimer::singleShot(1000, producer, SLOT(slot_publishResourceAddress()) );
}

void MainWindow::slot_log(QString str)
{
    qWarning( QString("LOG> %1").arg(str).toUtf8() );
}

void MainWindow::createConnections( void )
{
    connect(this, SIGNAL(signal_log(QString)), this, SLOT(slot_log(QString)));
    emit signal_log(QString("Log working!"));

    connect(producer, SIGNAL(signal_resourceAddress(uint_fast8_t*)), consumer, SLOT(slot_resource(uint_fast8_t*)));
}

void MainWindow::createProducer( void )
{
     producer = new SingleProducer();
     thread_producer = new QThread();
     producer->moveToThread(thread_producer); // THIS LINE DESERVES ATTENTION
     connect(producer, SIGNAL(signal_log(QString)), this, SLOT(slot_log(QString)));
}
```

singleproducer.h

```
#ifndef SINGLEPRODUCER_H
#define SINGLEPRODUCER_H

#include <QWidget>

class SingleProducer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SingleProducer(QObject *parent = nullptr);

signals:
    void signal_resourceAddress( uint_fast8_t* addr );
    void signal_log(QString str);
public slots:

    void slot_publishResourceAddress( void )
    {
        emit signal_log( QString("PRODUCER: sent resource address: %1").arg((long int) &un_resources__) );
        qWarning(QString("PRODUCER: sent resource address: %1").arg((long int) &un_resources__).toUtf8());
        emit signal_resourceAddress( &un_resources__ );
    }


private:
    uint_fast8_t un_resources__;
};

#endif // SINGLEPRODUCER_H
```

The editor doesn't let me post more code... but I think that this is the most relevant part... if not, let me know. But I shared it at [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/DkDTbsa6)

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to actually start the `QThread`s after creating them in both `MainWindow::createProducer` and `MainWindow::createConsumer`. From the [documentation of the constructor of `QThread`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#QThread):

> Constructs a new `QThread` to manage a new thread. The parent takes ownership of the QThread. **The thread does not begin executing until start() is called**.

So all you need to do is call `thread_producer->start()` and `thread_consumer->start()` respectively after creating the threads.